# Choose number at random from a range of numbers - Python

Tags: python, random

I'm making a game and I would like make my char's damage range(4,7),

To inflict damage, im doing enemyhp - chardamage, How would I make chardamage a random number from the `range(4,7)`?

Comment: Did you try Googling? I found `random.randint` in the first result.

Comment: python has a pretty good introspection features.  And often times you can stumble on what you need.  From the python CLI, try import random, and then dir(random).  The if something looks promising try help(random.interestingthing).

Comment: Do you mean Python's `range(4, 7)` (== `[4, 5, 6]`), or did you mean `[4, 5, 6, 7]`?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this using [`random.randrange`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.randrange):

```
random.randrange(4, 8)
```

You need to use 8 because in Python, the range is *inclusive* of the lower bound and *exclusive* of the upper bound.

Answer (score 2):

```
import random
print random.randint(4,7)
```

....

if you want floats then

```
print random.uniform(4,7)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import random

damage = random.randint(4, 7) # To get random num from {4,5,6,7}
```

Comment: Note that `randint()` behaves differently from `randrange()`, and you would need to use `randint(4, 7)` to get a random integer from `{4, 5, 6, 7}`.

Answer (score 2):

You need `range(4,8)` because the upper bound is always -1. `range(4,7)` will give you `4,5,6`

```
from random import choice
choice(range(4,8))
```

Comment: Python actually lets you use `xrange` there (for Python 2 users), and gives the right results :)